# which of the following statements are true in ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

which of the following statements are true in ring theory?

> (a) Let $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $I$ be an ideal. Then $R/I$ is an integral domain.
>   (b) If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity the units of $R[x]$ are the units in $R$.

(a) I think it is not true as $R/I$ is an integral domain iff I is an prime ideal but I have no counter example.
(b) I have no idea.

can I get some help.Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: (a) Okay - so, can you give me a commutative ring with unity, and a non-prime ideal? If so, calculate R/I, and see what you get. (b) What's your definition of R[x]? Can x ever be a unit, for example?

Answer (score 2):

(a) Which ideals are prime in $\mathbb Z$?

(b) Hint: $(1-aX)(1+aX)=1-a^2X^2$.

What happens if $R$ is a ring and $a \in R$ is such that $a^2=0$? Can you think of any such ring?

Answer (score 1):

(a): Think of a ring $R$ that is not an integral domain, and let $I$ be the zero ideal, i.e. $I=\{0\}$.

(b): Remember, given a ring $S$, we say that an element $y\in S$ is a unit when there is some $z\in S$ such that $yz=1_S$ (the symbol $1_S$ denotes the multiplicative identity element of $S$).

The polynomial ring $R[x]$ consists of polynomials whose coefficients are elements of $R$:
$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n,$$
where $n$ can be any integer greater than $0$, and each of the $a_i$'s come from $R$. They are added and multiplied like any other polynomials you have worked with before.

Clearly, if $a\in R$ is a unit (so that there is some $b\in R$ such that $ab=1_R$), then the polynomial
$$a+0x+0x^2+\cdots$$
is a unit in $R[x]$, because
$$\begin{align*}
(a+0x+0x^2+\cdots)(b+0x+0x^2+\cdots)&=ab+(a0+0b)x+(a0+0+0b)x^2+\cdots\\
&=ab+0x+0x^2+\cdots\\
&=1_R+0x+0x^2+\cdots
\end{align*}$$
and $1_R+0x+0x^2+\cdots$ is the mutliplicative identity of $R[x]$. (Usually, we don't bother writing all of these $0x^i$ terms, and just think of elements of $R$ as **also** being elements of $R[x]$. These elements of $R[x]$ are called **constant polynomials**.)

The question is whether there can be units of $R[x]$, other than the units of $R$ themselves. Thus, we're looking for non-constant polynomials (i.e., polynomials with some $x$'s in them) that can be multiplied by other polynomials to produce $1$. For simplicity, you might first take a look at **linear** polynomials, i.e. polynomials with an $x$ term, but no $x^2,x^3,\ldots$ terms. Of course, there's no guarantee that if there are non-constant polynomials that are units, that any of them will be linear; but this is a good place to start.

So, let's say we have our ring $R$, and elements $a,b\in R$ (with $b\neq 0$, so that we're looking at a *non-constant* polynomial) such that the polynomial $a+bx\in R[x]$ is a unit. In fact, let's make an even bigger simplifying step: assume that $a+bx$ is its own inverse, or in other words, that
$$(a+bx)^2=a^2+2abx+b^2x^2=1.$$
(Again, we don't know that even if there are any polynomials that are units, and are linear, that they would do this; but again, it's a first thing to look at. Remember, mathematicians are lazy.)

This can only happen if $2ab=0$ and $b^2=0$ in $R$. Can you think of a ring $R$ and $a,b\in R$ satisfying these relations?

Comment: (a) got it. (b) no,cant find such a ring

Comment: Here's a hint: To find such a ring, try looking at the quotient rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for some small values of $n$.